# how do I accept user inputs and call functions based on the them?

Tags: haskell

```
import System.IO

makeGrid :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]]
makeGrid x y = replicate y . replicate x

startGame = do
putStrLn "Select a difficulty (1,2): "
difficulty <- getLine
|difficulty == '1' = makeGrid 3 3 False
|difficulty == '2' = makeGrid 5 5 False
|otherwise = putStrln "Wrong thing"
             some function            --start from beginning again
```

As you see, I have a function makeGrid. I want to take user input in startGame and call makeGrid based on the user input. Also do a while loop if possible, how should I do that?

Comment: `|difficulty == '1' =` is not the right syntax here. Try `if ... then ... else` or `case`.

Comment: In Haskell one normally splits things up into functions. So you might have a `parseDifficulty` function which goes from a string (note double quotes for string and single quotes for chars) like `”1”` to a `Maybe Difficultly` like 'Just Easy`. This could be by a `readDifficulty :: IO Difficulty` function like `readDifficulty = putStrLn “difficulty?” >> (fmap parseDifficulty getLine) >>= \d -> case d of Just d -> return d; Nothing -> readDifficulty`. Note that this also demonstrates how one may repeat an IO action. If you want to do cases inside a `do`, you need a `case`.

Comment: You also need to indent the contents of the `do` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import System.IO

playGame = do
  grid <- initializeGrid
  -- game code goes here

initializeGrid = do
  putStrLn "Select a difficulty (1,2): "
  getLine >>= \case -- "difficulty <- getLine" <newline> "case difficulty of" also ok
    "1" -> return $ makeGrid 3 3 False
    "2" -> return $ makeGrid 5 5 False
    _   -> do
      putStrln "Wrong thing"
      initializeGrid

makeGrid :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]]
makeGrid x y = replicate y . replicate x
```

Comment: It makes a lot of sense but gives an error : "The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression" at grid <- initializeGrid when I try to run it in platform

Comment: Yes, you didn't put game code where it goes. It complains that you aren't using `grid`. For testing, you can use `print grid` there.